# How to flip PathGeometry vertically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `PathGeometry` that I want to flip vertically. I have tried the following but it is not working, am I missing something?

```
PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
myPathGeometry.Figures.Add(myPathFigure);
PathGeometry flipMyPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
ScaleTransform transform = new ScaleTransform(0, -1);
flipMyPathGeometry = Geometry.Combine(Geometry.Empty, myPathGeometry, GeometryCombineMode.Union, transform);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big problem there is that your width will be zero.
The X and Y scales are factors. As in multipliers. Anything times Zero is zero.
Hence

```
ScaleTransform(0, -1);
```

Will give you something with no width.

You presumably want the same width and hence:

```
ScaleTransform(1, -1);
```

That might still have another problem if you want the thing to be flipped about it's centre but at least it ought to show up when you use it.

The CenterY calculation is perhaps less than obvious. You can work out the height of a geometry using it's bounds.

Since you're creating a new pathgeometry, maybe you want to retain the original without any transform.

I put some code together that manipulates a geometry from resources and uses it to add a path to a canvas.

Markup:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="Star">
        M16.001007,0L20.944,10.533997 32,12.223022 23.998993,20.421997 25.889008,32 16.001007,26.533997 6.1109924,32 8,20.421997 0,12.223022 11.057007,10.533997z
    </Geometry>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="MyButton_Click">
    </Button>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Name="myCanvas"/>
</Grid>
```

Code

```
    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Geometry geom = this.Resources["Star"] as Geometry;
        Geometry flipped = geom.Clone();
        var bounds = geom.Bounds;
        double halfY = (bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top) / 2.0;
        flipped.Transform = new ScaleTransform(1, -1, 0, halfY );
        PathGeometry pg = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(flipped);

        var path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path {Data=pg, Fill= System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red };
        this.myCanvas.Children.Add(path);
    }
```

Comment: You are right, I want to retain the original without any transform. However, I know it doesn't make sense but in my case the `flipped` shape has the same data of  original `geom`. It is not flipped for some reason!

Comment: Thank you @Andy, I knew what was my mistake. I will explain it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the PathGeometry's `Transform` property:

```
var myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
myPathGeometry.Figures.Add(myPathFigure);
myPathGeometry.Transform = new ScaleTransform(1, -1);
```

Note that you may also need to set the ScaleTransform's `CenterY` property for a correct vertical alignment.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I end up with the same original figure data!

Comment: Sorry, you would of course apply the transform to the original PathGeometry. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I already applied transform to the original PathGeometry, and it does not flip the shape. Here is what I expect, and please correct me if I am wrong. After using `ScaleTransform(1,-1)` the new Y values should not be the same original ones, right?!

Comment: No, the values stay the same. Just the rendering changes.

Answer (score 0):

Both @Andy and @Clemens gave right answers. The reason why I didn't get the expected shape is because I didn't notice that the shape is outside the screen region. However, I used Andy's solution because I need to keep the original shape. Also, he notified me about creating new bounds. The only thing I changed in his answer is the value of the new bounds because with the one that he used, the shape was still outside the screen region.

```
double newY = (bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top);
```