# Heart shaped image clip - rotate/scale a Geometry object

Tags: xaml, svg, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-8.0

#### Final goal

Clip an image with a shape of heart.

#### Attempt

I have converted the svg path data of [this source](https://codepen.io/PaulRyan17/pen/wvaMExg) into it's geometry equivalent. Except that I have to rotate the final `Geometry` object, unlike in wpf there is no such `Rotation` property or `RotateTo() ... Transform()` method defined for types `PathGeometry` and `PathFigure` since both inherit from `BindableObject` and not `VisualElement`.

#### Question

- I am stuck, how can I overcome this issue?
- Is there a way to make the image clipping object scalable/resizable?

```xml
<DataTemplate>
...
 <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
        Source="{Binding .}"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="300">
     <Image.Clip>
         <PathGeometry>
             <PathGeometry.Figures>
                 <PathFigureCollection>
                     <PathFigure IsClosed="False" StartPoint="0,200">
                         <PathFigure.Segments>
                             <PathSegmentCollection>
                                 <LineSegment Point="0,0" />
                                 <LineSegment Point="200,0" />
                                 <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True"
                                             Point="200,200"
                                             RotationAngle="90"
                                             Size="100,100"
                                             SweepDirection="Clockwise" />

                                 <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True"
                                             Point="0,200"
                                             RotationAngle="90"
                                             Size="100,100"
                                             SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                             </PathSegmentCollection>
                         </PathFigure.Segments>
                     </PathFigure>
                 </PathFigureCollection>
             </PathGeometry.Figures>
         </PathGeometry>
     </Image.Clip>
 </Image>
...
<DataTemplate>
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

**Red**: is the desired shape.

**Blue**: is the actual clip that needs to be rotated to obtain the red one.

Note that the blue and red shapes are exactly **the same shape** (data path), with only difference the **rotation**.

```html
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
version="1.1" height="315" width="342" viewBox="20 -10 315 342">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    .outline { stroke:none; stroke-width:0 }
  ]]></style>
   <g id="heart">
   <path
    stroke="red"
    pathLength="1"
    stroke-width="5"
    d="M0 200 v-200 h200 
    a100,100 90 0,1 0,200
    a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0
    z" />
  </g>
 </defs>
 <desc>
   a nearly perfect heart
     made of two arcs and a right angle
 </desc>
  <use xlink:href="#heart" class="outline " fill="none" transform="rotate(225,150,121)" />
</svg>
```

Basically this is what you get without the rotation:

```html
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
version="1.1" height="315" width="342" viewBox="20 -10 315 342">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    .outline { stroke:none; stroke-width:0 }
  ]]></style>
   <g id="heart">
   <path
    stroke="red"
    pathLength="1"
    stroke-width="5"
    d="M0 200 v-200 h200 
    a100,100 90 0,1 0,200
    a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0
    z" />
  </g>
 </defs>
 <desc>
   a nearly perfect heart
     made of two arcs and a right angle
 </desc>
  <use xlink:href="#heart" class="outline " fill="none"" />
</svg>
```

ps: I am open to other approaches.

Wpf: [How to flip PathGeometry vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55549011/)

Comment: a screenshot illustrating what you're trying to do would be helpful.  Have you tried rotating the Image object?

Comment: @Jason i will add a screenshot, rotating the image won't help because the image is in the good rotation, the clip shape (geometry) isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the svg geometry you can take advantage of many javaScript based tools/libraries to transform paths to "hardcoded"  path data commands.

You can use the [svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) to conveniently recalculate all path commands according to rotation.

1. apply a transformation/rotation
2. apply x/y offsets via translate to realign the path data based on it's bounding box – use browser supported JS [`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method to get the appropriate offsets.
3. convert commands to all absolute

The final path data should look something like this

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 342 312" style="border:1px solid #ccc; height:90vmin">
  <path 
d="
   M 312.42 170.58 
   L 171 312 
   L 29.58 170.58 
   A 100 100 0 0 1 171 29.16 
   A 100 100 0 0 1 312.42 170.58 
"/></svg>
```

BTW: if arc `rx` and `ry` radii parameters (1. and 2. `A` command parameter) are equal – the arc is perfectly circular (or non-elliptical) so a specified rotation angle doesn't have any rendering effect – so it can be set to 0.

According to [MS docs: "How to: Create an Elliptical Arc"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-an-elliptical-arc?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) you should be able to translate these SVG values like so

| wpf/xaml | svg |
| --- | --- |
| `StartPoint="312.42, 170.58"` | `M 312.42 170.58` |
| `LineSegment Point="171,312"` | `L 171 312` |
| `LineSegment Point="29.58,170.58"` | `L 29.58 170.58` |
| `ArcSegment Size="100,100" RotationAngle="0" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="171,29.16"` | `A 100 100 0 1 1 171 29.16` |
| **wpf/xaml arc to SVG terminology:** Size=[rx,rx] (x and y radius ... calling it "size" ... no comment), RotationAngle=x-axis-rotation, IsLargeArc=largeArc flag, SweepDirection=sweep flag(1 =clockwise; 0=counterclockwise) Point=[x,y] (final on-path point) See also ["W3C spec: §9.3.8. The elliptical arc curve commands"](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) |  |
| `ArcSegment Size="100,100" RotationAngle="0" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="312.42,170.58"` | `A 100 100 0 1 1 312.42 170.58` |

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed and explained answer

Comment: I was exactly looking for a tool to help embed the rotation action into a coordinates change instead; `svg-path-editor` is really useful.